# Bootstrap popover not working on disabled element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am wanting a `popover` to appear, if a user clicks on a disabled element. Looking at [Bootstrap's guide](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), it says to put the element inside of a `<div>` and apply the popover to that `<div>` instead.

My code is:

```
<div id="disabled">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" disabled="disabled" id="edit" 
     class="btn ban-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" 
     data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet 
     rutrum faucibus.">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp; Edit</button>
</div>
```

Initialised at the top of the page:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#disabled").popover()
});

</script>
```

But when I click on the disabled button, a  popover doesn't appear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the duplicated class attribute from the button, then move all the data attributes related to the popover to the wrapper div. Don't forget to add a title data attribute aswell.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Enrico. That works perfectly. Such an underweight on my behalf. Please add this as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: you're welcome, we all make mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the duplicated class attribute from the button, then move all the data attributes related to the popover to the wrapper div. Don't forget to add a title data attribute aswell.